# Get human readable cpu frequency

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to get a simplified output of the cpu frequency to 3 digits, such that if the frequency is less than 1000 it will output `xxx Mhz` and if it's above 1000 it will outpute `x.xx Ghz`. I can get only the frequency with `lscpu | sed -n 's/CPU MHz:[ \t]*//p'`, and the first 4 digits with `lscpu | sed -n 's/CPU MHz:[ \t]*//p' | cut -c1-4`, however I'm not sure how to parse this to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
lscpu | awk '/CPU MHz/{if($NF+0>1000)printf "%.3f GHz\n",$NF/1000; else printf "%.3f MHz\n",$NF}'
```

#### How it works

- `/CPU MHz/{...}`

  This selects the line we want and executes the commands in curly braces only for that line.
- `if($NF+0>1000)printf "%.3f GHz\n",$NF/1000; else printf "%.3f MHz\n",$NF`

  If the final field, `$NF`, is greater than 1000, then we divide it by 1000 and print it as GHz.  Otherwise, we print it as MHz.  The format `%.3f` determines how many significant digits are printed.  Adjust this to suit your tastes.

#### Multi-line version

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
lscpu | awk '
    /CPU MHz/{
        if($NF+0>1000)
            printf "%.3f GHz\n",$NF/1000
        else
            printf "%.3f MHz\n",$NF
    }'
```